stats_get_csv is killing my download speed in my plugin
I'm building a plugin that exports posts to a CSV. The thing is, I'm using the stats_get_csv function from Jetpack to get the views for each post, and it's slowing down my download speed to 100 Bytes/s. It's a disaster.
My function to get views:
function get_page_views($post_id)
{

    $cache_key = 'post_views_'.$post_id;
    $views = wp_cache_get($cache_key);

    if ($views === false) {
        if (function_exists('stats_get_csv')) {
            $args = array('days' => -1, 'limit' => -1, 'post_id' => $post_id);
            $result = stats_get_csv('postviews', $args);
            $views = intval($result[0]['views']);
        } else {
            $views = 0;
        }

        wp_cache_set($cache_key, $views, 'post_views', 300);
    }

    return $views;
}

part of my export function:
foreach ($results as $post) {

    $views = wp_cache_get('post_views_'.$post->ID);
    if ($views === false) {
        $views = get_page_views($post->ID);
        error_log('Visitas obtenidas de la forma original para el post_id: '.$post->ID.', visitas: '.$views);
    } else {
        error_log('Visitas obtenidas de la caché para el post_id: '.$post->ID.', visitas: '.$views);
    }

    fputcsv($output, array(
        $post->ID,
        $post->post_title,
        get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author),
        implode(', ', wp_get_post_categories($post->ID, ['fields' => 'names'])),
        $views,
        $post->post_date,
    ));

    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

What I've already tried and didn't work:
I tried doing a direct SQL query to get the post views instead of calling stats_get_csv for each one. But it didn't work because it fetches different views, not the same ones.
I thought about using transients to cache the results of stats_get_csv and avoid repeated calls during the export. But nope, it didn't improve things.
I attempted to fetch all the data at once to avoid multiple requests. But I get a timeout before I can export. It's a bummer.
Honestly, I don't know what else to try. I feel like the meme of the guy looking at the piece of paper with a suffering face.
If anyone has any ideas or experience with this function and can lend me a hand, I'll be eternally grateful. I need to solve this, otherwise my plugin is going to be slow as hell.

$result = stats_get_csv('postviews', $args); - what actual result is this giving you? You are only accessing $result[0]['views'] afterwards, so I am guessing, this is probably gathering a lot more data, than actually necessary? Does this really need to be called with 'days' => -1, to get the data you are actually interested in?
